# How do I create an Iterator for a QuadTree that yields each point, the leaf it is in, and the neighbouring leaves?

Tags: algorithm, rust, iterator, quadtree

I have a simple `QuadTree`. For readability and to help me understand what is happening, It avoids recursion and has a static depth. The `QuadTree` stores references to the points that are owned by another container.

```
struct QuadLeaf<'a> {
    vec: Vec<&'a (f32,f32)>,
    rect: (f32, f32, f32, f32)
}
struct QuadTwig<'a> {
    cells: [QuadLeaf<'a>; 4],
}
struct QuadBranch<'a> {
    cells: [QuadTwig<'a>; 4],
}
struct QuadTree<'a> {
    cells: [QuadBranch<'a>; 4],
}
```

Constructing and inserting into this tree is relatively simple. The `QuadLeaf` is constructed with a bounding `rect` and an empty `vec`, and has a method that attempts to insert a point. It returns true if the point is within the `rect` and has been inserted.

```
impl<'a> QuadLeaf<'a> {
    fn new(rect: (f32, f32, f32, f32)) -> Self {
        QuadLeaf {vec: Vec::new(),rect}
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, point: &'a (f32, f32)) -> bool {
        if is_point_in_rect(point.0, point.1, self.rect) {
            self.vec.push(point);
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

The `QuadTwig` `new` function splits the bounding `rect` into 4 and creates 4 new `QuadLeaf`s . It's `insert` function attempts to insert into each leaf, short circuiting when it is successful, and returning false if unsuccessful.

```
impl<'a> QuadTwig<'a> {
    fn new(rect: (f32, f32, f32, f32)) -> Self {
        let rects = divide_into_4(rect);
        QuadTwig {
            cells: [
                QuadLeaf::new(rects[0]),
                QuadLeaf::new(rects[1]),
                QuadLeaf::new(rects[2]),
                QuadLeaf::new(rects[3])
            ]
        }
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, point: &'a (f32, f32)) -> bool {
        for cell in self.cells.iter_mut() {
            if cell.insert(point) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        false
    }
}
```

The implementations for `QuadBranch` and `QuadTree` are exactly the same, but the `new` function just constructs the next level down in the tree. This could be refactored later for less code duplication, but for demonstration purposes I will leave it. I also think it does not matter for the context of this question.

**Question:**

I want to create an Iterator that yields each point in the tree, and the 9 leaves that it is close to (or inside of).

I have managed to create a simpler version, that just yields each point and the leaf it is in:

```
/// An Iterator that yields each point and the leaf it is in
struct PointAndLeafIterator<'a> {
    ptr: &'a QuadTree<'a>,
    index: (usize, usize, usize, usize)
}

/// An Iterator that yields each point and the leaf it is in
impl<'a> Iterator for PointAndLeafIterator<'a> {
    /// Returns (point, leaf)
    type Item = (&'a (f32, f32), Vec<&'a (f32, f32)>);

    /// Starts at (0,0,0,0) and ends at (3, 3, 3, num_points_in_leaf)
    /// It increases the index by 1 each time, and if it reaches the end of the cell, it moves to the next cell
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let (branch_index, twig_index, leaf_index, point_index) = &mut self.index;
        let branch = &self.ptr.cells[*branch_index];
        let twig = &branch.cells[*twig_index];
        let leaf = &twig.cells[*leaf_index];
        let point = leaf.vec.get(*point_index);
        //go through all the points in the leaf
        if let Some(point) = point {
            *point_index += 1;
            return Some((point, leaf.vec.clone()));
        }

        //if we reach the end of the leaf, go to the next leaf
        *point_index = 0;
        *leaf_index += 1;
        if *leaf_index < 4 {
            return self.next();
        }

        //if we reach the end of the twig, go to the next twig
        *leaf_index = 0;
        *twig_index += 1;
        if *twig_index < 4 {
            return self.next();
        }

        //if we reach the end of the branch, go to the next branch
        *twig_index = 0;
        *branch_index += 1;
        if *branch_index < 4 {
            return self.next();
        }

        //if we reach the end of the tree, we are done
        None

    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
fn main() {
    let points: Vec<(f32, f32)> = vec![
        (0.0, 0.0),
        (1.0, 1.0),
        (31.0,31.0),
        (2.0, 2.0),
        (3.0, 3.0),
        (32.0,32.0),
    ];
    let mut quadtree = QuadTree::new((0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0));
    for point in points.iter() {
        quadtree.insert(point);
    }
    for (point, leaf) in quadtree.into_point_and_leaf_iter() {
        println!("Point: {:?}", point);
        println!("Leaf: {:?}", leaf);
    }
}
```

However the neighbouring version is proving to be much more difficult. How can I write this algorithm?

```
/// An Iterator that yields each point, the leaf it is in, and the neighbouring leaves
struct PointAndLeafAndNeighboursIterator<'a> {
    ptr: &'a QuadTree<'a>,
    index: (usize, usize, usize, usize)
}

impl<'a> Iterator for PointAndLeafAndNeighboursIterator<'a> {
    ///Return the 9 leaves that surround the point
    ///If there is no leaf in a direction, it will return an empty leaf
    type Item = (&'a (f32, f32), [Vec<&'a (f32, f32)>; 9]);

    /// Starts at (0,0,0,0) and ends at (3, 3, 3, num_points_in_leaf)
    /// It increases the index by 1 each time, and if it reaches the end of the cell, it moves to the next cell
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

[Here is a Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=851858f1eef9cd06783163ea5f0aa1ab) to all code in this question.

Comment: Once you've identified the leaf that contains the point, can you just see which other leaves have matching rectangle boundary coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfe755583aac7cffea99894d3d79f1b5).

First I added indexing by leaf indices since the `QuadTree` struct is basically an 8x8 matrix of leaves.

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct QuadLeafId {
    x: i8,
    y: i8,
}

impl QuadLeafId {
    fn new(x: i8, y: i8) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }

    fn level_index(&self, level: usize) -> usize {
        (((self.y >> level) % 2) * 2 + ((self.x >> level) % 2)) as usize
    }

    /// Extract the QuadTwig array index containing this leaf
    fn twig_index(&self) -> usize {
        self.level_index(0)
    }

    /// Extract the QuadBranch array index containing this leaf
    fn branch_index(&self) -> usize {
        self.level_index(1)
    }

    /// Extract the QuadTree array index containing this leaf
    fn tree_index(&self) -> usize {
        self.level_index(2)
    }
}

impl<'a> Index<QuadLeafId> for QuadTwig<'a> {
    type Output = QuadLeaf<'a>;
    fn index(&self, index: QuadLeafId) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.cells[index.twig_index()]
    }
}

impl<'a> Index<QuadLeafId> for QuadBranch<'a> {
    type Output = QuadLeaf<'a>;
    fn index(&self, index: QuadLeafId) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.cells[index.branch_index()][index]
    }
}

impl<'a> Index<QuadLeafId> for QuadTree<'a> {
    type Output = QuadLeaf<'a>;
    fn index(&self, index: QuadLeafId) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.cells[index.tree_index()][index]
    }
}
```

Then added iterating over nearby leaves in a `QuadTree`

```
impl QuadLeafId {
    /// The ids of the 9 nearby leaves
    fn near_ids(self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Self> {
        (-1..=1).flat_map(move |x| {
            (-1..=1).map(move |y| Self {
                x: self.x + x,
                y: self.y + y,
            })
        })
    }

    fn is_valid(&self) -> bool {
        0 <= self.y && self.y < 8 && 0 <= self.x && self.x < 8
    }
}

impl<'a> QuadTree<'a> {
    fn get_leaf(&self, id: QuadLeafId) -> Option<&QuadLeaf<'a>> {
        id.is_valid().then(|| &self[id])
    }

    fn near_leaves(&self, id: QuadLeafId) -> impl Iterator<Item = Option<&QuadLeaf<'a>>> {
        id.near_ids().map(|id| self.get_leaf(id))
    }
}
```

Implementing the iterator afterwards is straightforward:

```
impl QuadLeafId {
    fn next_id(mut self) -> Option<Self> {
        self.x += 1;
        if self.x < 8 {
            return Some(self);
        }

        self.x = 0;
        self.y += 1;
        (self.y < 8).then_some(self)
    }
}

impl<'a> QuadTree<'a> {
    fn into_point_and_leaf_and_neighbours_iter(
        &'a mut self,
    ) -> PointAndLeafAndNeighboursIterator<'a> {
        PointAndLeafAndNeighboursIterator::<'a> {
            ptr: self,
            index: Some(QuadLeafId::new(0, 0)),
            point_index: 0,
        }
    }
}

/// An Iterator that yields each point, the leaf it is in, and the neighboring leaves
struct PointAndLeafAndNeighboursIterator<'a> {
    ptr: &'a QuadTree<'a>,
    index: Option<QuadLeafId>,
    point_index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for PointAndLeafAndNeighboursIterator<'a> {
    ///Return the 9 leaves that surround the point
    ///If there is no leaf in a direction, it will return an empty leaf
    type Item = (&'a (f32, f32), [Vec<&'a (f32, f32)>; 9]);

    /// Starts at (0,0,0,0) and ends at (3, 3, 3, num_points_in_leaf)
    /// It increases the index by 1 each time, and if it reaches the end of the cell, it moves to the next cell
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        loop {
            let ind = self.index?;
            let leaf = &self.ptr[ind];
            if let Some(point) = leaf.vec.get(self.point_index) {
                self.point_index += 1;
                let mut iter = self
                    .ptr
                    .near_leaves(ind)
                    .map(|leaf| leaf.map(|leaf| leaf.vec.clone()).unwrap_or_default());
                return Some((*point, [(); 9].map(|_| iter.next().unwrap())));
            }
            self.point_index = 0;
            self.index = ind.next_id();
        }
    }
}
```